# How do I switch screens with KivyMD toolbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I made a very basic App, with KivyMD bottom App bar. I am having issues when I trying to use the toolbar icons to switch screen.

*here's my main.py file* (please bear with me, my code is a little clustered from me implementing some solutions I found, which didnt work)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 500)


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class TwoScreenApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Gray'
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))

        return sm

    def callback(self, screen):
        self.current = screen
        # root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        # root.manager.current = 'screen2'
        # link icon to screen2



TwoScreenApp().run()
```

here's my .kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>
    name: 'screen1'
    MDBoxLayout:
    md_bg_color: (255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1)
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDLabel:
        halign: 'center'
        text:
            """With the production of the Model T automobile,
            Henry Ford had an unforeseen and tremendous
            impact on American life. He became regarded
            as an apt symbol of the transition from an
            agricultural to an industrial America."""

    MDBottomAppBar:

        MDToolbar:
            icon: "account-circle"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["arrow-right", lambda x: root.manager.callback("screen1")]]
            right_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: x]]
            elevation: 10

<Screen2>
    name: 'screen2'
    md_bg_color: (200/255, 200/255, 200/255, 1)

    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color: (255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1)
        orientation: 'vertical'

    MDLabel:
        halign: 'center'
        text:
            """The development of mass-production techniques, which
            enabled the company eventually to turn out a Model T
            every 24 seconds; the frequent reductions in the price
            of the car made possible by economies of scale; and
            the payment of a living wage that raised workers
            above subsistence and made them potential customers
            for, among other things, automobiles—these innovations
            changed the very structure of society."""

    MDBottomAppBar:

        MDToolbar:
            title: "Title"
            icon: "account-circle"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
left_action_items: [["arrow-right", lambda x: root.manager.callback("screen1")]]
```

is trying to call the `callback()` method of `root.manager`, which is the `ScreenManager`. But `ScreenManager` does not have a `callback()` method. I think you want to call the `callback()` method of your `TwoScreenApp`, which you would do like this:

```
left_action_items: [["arrow-right", lambda x: app.callback("screen2")]]
```

which uses the `app` keyword to reference the `App` instance.

Comment: I've called the callback method like you said.. I also created a, "def callback(self)"  in my main.py file but I am still getting a, "NameError: name 'callback' is not defined" error, I think the issue is in my main,py file i.e with the "def callback(self)", so please my question is how will my main.py file look like?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `app.callback()` is calling the `callback()` method of your `App` (`TwoScreenApp`). You should still have that method in your `TwoScreenApp` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot I have finally got it, my issue now is that I want the bottom App bar to be on multiple screens.. I am aware that I need to create a main class and let inherit it, I would love if you could show me a sample, Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that should be a separately posted question.

Comment: John Thank you for your contribution. I have posted the question, and I hope to hear from you..